# Why is my 2005 Husaberg FE550 stalling when it gets hot?

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, stall

My 2005 Husaberg FE550 runs great until it gets hot, then suddenly stalls. If I let it cool a couple of minutes I can start it right back up, but it continues to do this over and over. Could it be the Stator, Rectifier, Coil??? This just started happening recently. Please advise. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated---maybe DukatiKiller knows?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Unfortunately, DukatiKiller doesn't do much on here anymore (very unfortunate). As for your issue, usually if an engine will start and run, then dies, it's usually a fueling problem. It could just be the vent cap on your gas tank is not allowing air to go into the tank fast enough, causes a vacuum inside the tank, then starves it from fuel. Then, after the tank gets a chance to equalize, it'll run again. Try running it with the gas cap off and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Are valves adjusted periodically. Can you test for spark right after the engine dies?

Answer (score 1):

problems like this can be caused by a bad coil. they may work fine when cool and then cut out when hot. coils are tricky to test. try one from another bike.